# Using Java POJO in Scala codebase

Tags: java, scala

I have the following class [Java class in a Scala codebase]

```
public class JobConfigTest {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String name;

    public JobConfigTest(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And i am trying to do the below operation -

```
 val obj = new JobConfigTest("Hello")
    obj.setName("Hello")
    println(obj.getName)
```

The error i get is -

```
no arguments allowed for nullary constructor JobConfigTest: ()com.something.data.config.JobConfigTest
    val obj = new JobConfigTest("Hello")
```

The same codebase works in Java codebase with Java compiler. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Is the `@data` annotation from Lombok? If yes, you should review the documentation because you have some redundant code: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: Yes, Removing @Data does not do any change.

Comment: Don't you need a no-arg constructor?